# SQL Join with logical operators

Tags: mysql, join

Data structure and example:

```
Employees
id  name
1   Mike Jensen
2   Lisa Miller

Skills
eid name
1   SQL
1   PHP
```

Query for Employees with Skills SQL or PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Skills ON (Employees.id = Skills.eid) WHERE Skills.name = "SQL" OR Skills.name = "PHP" GROUP BY Employees.id
```

Query for Employees with Skills SQL and PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees LEFT JOIN Skills ON (Employees.id = Skills.eid) WHERE Skills.name = "SQL" OR Skills.name = "PHP" GROUP BY Employees.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

But what would the query look like for Employees with Skills PHP and (SQL or JS)?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0f1f/6

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Query for Employees with Skills SQL and PHP

UNION

Query for Employees with Skills SQL and JS

If your tables are small enough, the performance penalty won't hurt too much.
BTW the use of a left outer join doesn't make sense as the where clause will eliminate the rows that don't match.

Comment: Union  is not intersection

Comment: @splash58 the question was: SQL AND (PHP OR JS), which is the same as (SQL AND PHP) OR (SQL AND JS). Hence the UNION to build the OR, and the rest has been answered by the OP already